# Find the derivative of order $2021$, at the point $x=0$, of $\ln\left(2021+e^{x^{2021}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Find the derivative of order $2021$, at the point $x=0$, of $\ln\left(2021+e^{x^{2021}}\right)$.

I tried taking derivatives in order to derive the formula.

I tried to decompose it according to the Leibniz formula, but I didn't get any further.

I assume that the answer will be $0$, but I can't justify it strictly. What can you recommend?

Comment: If you are in a hurry and cannot learn Latex, you can alternatively type your expression in Desmos and copy and paste it in your edit, surrounded by $ sign to get Math expressions. https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:**

Note that your function is equal to

$$\ln(2021) + \ln\Big(1+\frac{e^{x^{2021}}}{2021}\Big)$$

and the latter logarithm can be expanded using the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+y)$ about $y=0$, yielding

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\Big(\frac{e^{x^{2021}}}{2021}\Big)^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\frac{e^{nx^{2021}}}{2021^n}$$

We may additionally expand $e^{nx^{2021}}$ according to its Maclaurin series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \frac{n^m x^{2021m}}{2021^n m!}$$

Now we have a double infinite series of powers of $x$. If we take $2021$ derivatives and evaluate at $x=0$, the only contribution will come from the $x^{2021}$ terms.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I’d rather factor out $2022$ instead of taking it from here. ;-)